# Does this rule I found really work?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-explanation, exponentiation, fractions

I was playing a bit whit exponents. I maybe found a working formula for calculating $n^y$ if you know $n^x$. The formula may already be discovered, but the formula I found is:
$$ (n^x)^\frac{y}{x} = n^y $$
Ok, so the formula should work if $n,x,y \in \mathbb N$

I am not sure if it does work whit negative and decimal numbers tho.

Ok, my questions are:
 1. Can the formula be used whit decimal, and negative numbers (x,y,n)
 2. Can you prove that the formula works if $x,y,n \in \mathbb N$, if it is possible also for $x,y,n \in \mathbb Q$, $x,y,n \in \mathbb R$ and  $x,y,n \in \mathbb Z$.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork, thank you so much. I am new to exponents and all that. I dont really know all the rules yet.

Comment: Of course, it's a good question, and it takes more work than one might imagine to prove this for arbitrary $x,y,n\in\mathbb{R}$

Comment: @DavidG.Stork  The rule fails if $n$ is negative and $x$ is even.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $n=-1$, $x=2$ and $y=1$.  Then you have

$$((-1)^2)^{1/2} = 1^{1/2} = 1$$

but

$$(-1)^1 = -1.$$

So your rule fails.

Comment: Ok, that is true. But what if we |x| (absolute value) the result?

Comment: @CppPythonDude  Then you have a rule that works on half of the fields you mentioned.  What about complex numbers?   There are 4 fourth roots of $-1$, so I could cook up an example where the absolute value won't fix the problem.

Comment: Can i somehow fix the rule then?

Comment: If you add the condition that $x>0$ the rule will work.  In general, when you see fractional exponents and negative bases, trouble is lurking at every turn.

Comment: I think the restrictions you want are $n>0$, $x\neq0$.

Answer (score 0):

That is one of the exponent rules.

The rule is: $(x^a)^b = x^{ab}$,  But generally, you can't get $n^y$ if you have $n^x$, per example if you have $7^{12}$, you can't get $7^{20} = 7^{12} \cdot 7^8$, without calculating $7^8$.